# Laravel 4 get previous url on filter

Tags: laravel-4

I have form, which the post action will goes to ajax filter (only permit ajax post). If its not ajax, I want the page will be redirected to the submitted form page (previous page). URL::previous just result undefined.

```
Route::filter('ajax', function() {
    if (Request::ajax() === false)
            //URL::previous()      
});
```

I use laravel 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to place a comment but I don't have enough rep.

Did you try the following option?

```
Redirect::back()->withErrors('error', 'Not a ajax post');
```

Or without a message

```
Redirect::back();
```